# An internal response header size limit was exceeded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

[image]

This error occurrs when I perform a redirect to another part of the site in question.

```
return this.RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Dashboard"
```

The code does not step into the Index method in the Dashboard controller before the error occurs.

[image]

I think the Fiddler response header posted is not the >internal< Response header in the error message.

Could anyone explain how best to increase the size limit of the internal response header?

Or, Are we looking at needing to compress the internal response header as a solution?

For your information the call to redirect above was working day in day out for about 3 months until it broke about 5 days ago.

[Edit 1]
The program.cs file is now looking like:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().ConfigureKestrel((context, options) => {
            options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = 1024000;
            options.Limits.Http2.HeaderTableSize = 16384;
        });
```

However, the same error is still occurring.

[Edit 2 18.03.19 2:28am]
The problem was caused by a User Claim not being filled in (Identity Table) on one of the profile users. I filled the data in manually in SSMS and the error stopped occurring.

TIA.

David

Comment: This question relates to .net core 2.2

Comment: please refer your event-log and see if any further information is available

Comment: If not enabled already, enable stdoutLogEnabled and make sure you create a Logs folder or you'll get could not create stdoutFile error

Comment: This is the last line in the log file I recall reading a post where there is a 21s timeout which relates to the ms illustrated here / Can anyone say how to increase this timeout /  info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 20905.785ms 301

Comment: I expected this, here's the solution https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/48

Comment: @kowsikbabu / I have updated post with some changes. I could not see any other Kestrel changes I needed. I made project run as Out-Of-Process in Properties->Debug. Any other pointers? NB: Last line of log file is now: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 24869.2948ms 301

Comment: David, do change the keepalivetimeout to 5 seconds and see if it is reflecting in the log

Comment: @kowsikbabu Nope the change had no effect on the relevant line. One thing to note we are serving on HTTP/1.1

Comment: okay, now maybe change the timeout in IIS to 5 minutes and then host the application on IIS

Comment: A new development / This is a login area / One profile gets past the same error / Another profile does not. Hosting on IIS and trying as you suggest. Also trying to work out why one of the profiles is not working very well.

Comment: This line Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult loSignInResult = await this._oLoginManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loUser, lsPassword, true, true); causes the header issue. If I step over this line without executing it, the problem does not manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar issue, for me
this was caused by a bug in WinHTTP which happened long time ago (core 2.0). When a redirect response occurs, WinHTTP prefers to reuse the same connection to follow the redirect. 
The number of response bytes drained is controlled by the WinHttpHandler.MaxResponseDrainSize.
When the response size exceeds MaxResponseDrainSize the request is aborted with specified error.

The issue disappeared when i upgraded to 2.1

- Update **Timout Issue**

The settings you add as KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); applies to Kestrel but not IIS.
There is a reverse proxy setup between IIS and Kestrel. So you made the Timeout of Kestrel to 5 Min. But IIS sits with default timeout which is 120sec. You can change the time out in 
***IIS->Sites->Select your Site->Advanced Settings ->Limits->Connection Time Out***. 
Try changing this settings to check whether this error happens.

Also there is another setting available in Configuration Editor
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have read this post I think. I am using 2.2 / Please see my last comment on previous post to see the log result and 21s timeout possibility.

Comment: The settings you add as KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); applies to Kestrel but not IIS.

Comment: Can you setup reverse proxy on IISExpress?

Comment: Haven't done that, you dont need to do this by yourself for solving this issue. please check this url if you need to know more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing.